# Two parameters for Rails3 scope

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, named-scope

Currently i have two models: Rate and Item

**Rate** is a model for voting, and there is **votes** and **player_id**

Rate has_many :votes
Vote belongs_to :rate

Also, for Item model, currently i have a scope like:

```
scope :pop, proc { order('votes.votes DESC') }
```

to sort all Items by **vote**.

The question is: i need to collect items sorted (Item.all.pop) **AND** by player_id
Something like: Item.all.pop(player_id)

How it could be done?

*Update:*

**rate.rb**

```
class Rate < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :player
  belongs_to :item
end
```

**item.rb**

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :rates
  scope :pop, proc { order('rates.votes DESC') }
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE: (based on post update and comment clarifications)

You probably want something like this:

```
scope :pop, order('stats.votes DESC')

scope :for_player, lambda{|player| joins(:rates).where(:player_id => player.id)}
```

Then you should be able to call `Item.for_player(@my_player).pop`.

Disclaimer: I'm not great at building active record queries off the top of my head, so the above may need some tweaking...

---

(Original answer)

You probably want something like this:

```
scope :pop, order('stats.votes DESC')

scope :by_player, group('player_id')
```

Then, you should be able to do `Item.by_player.pop` and get what you want. (You can check in the console with `Item.by_player.pop.to_sql` to see if the expected SQL query is generated.)

Comment: Hey David! Yes, but the problem is player_id is a part of Rate model, not Item (e.g. Rate is a model for voting, and there is votes and player_id). Also, i need something like Item.by_player(current_player.id).pop .Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you describe the relationship between Item and Rate?

Comment: Yes, but what about Item (in the first line)? Is Item the same as Vote?

Comment: Updated. So, generally, in the controller, i want something like: @items = Item.all.by_player(current_user).pop

Comment: When order(stats.votes DESC), it search by all votes in the Stat. But i have to scope not all records, but records with player_id given.